# Wordpress Update problemDownload failed.: SSL certificate

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I want to update my WordPress version to 4.0, right now it is WordPress 3.2.1.
When I try to update it, I am getting the below error:

> Download failed.: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>
> Installation Failed

What is the solution for it? Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Are you using any plugins? Specifically, any site-backup plugins?

Comment: yes i am using many plugins but none of them are related to site-backup plugins.

Answer (score 15):

I am able to resolve this issue by adding below code in functions.php of my theme folder.

```
add_action('http_request_args', 'jkudish_http_request_args', 10, 2);
function jkudish_http_request_args($args, $url) {
$args['sslverify'] = false;
return $args;
}
```

I hope this can help someone :)

Comment: Worked flawlessly, was able to upgrade to 4.3.1 with this tweek. I have an old Theme that I customized that I didn't want to upgrade!